# mysql regular expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

i'm trying to to look for all strings that start with the letter D. in my mysql query i have this.

```
REGEXP '^[D]{4}$'
```

Problem is it returns everything what stars with D and End with D too.

example:

```
DDD 123 - true
D 123 - true
DDDD 1234 - true

SSS 123 D - returns true, but should be false.
```

Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"...for all strings that start with the letter D"*

You can simply do it by using `LIKE`

```
WHERE columnName LIKE 'D%'
```

or this pattern in regex.

```
WHERE columnName REGEXP '^D.*'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b59d/2)

Comment: yeah but unfortunately i really need to use regex. need it for search thru license plate in my DB

Comment: `^[D]{4}$` will not match anything, right? because it looks for `DDDD`. see here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b59d/4

Comment: The set brackets `[...]` are only required if you're actually including more than one character. `[D]` is the same as `D`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where columnname RLIKE '^D'
```

or

```
select * from tablename where columnname REGEXP '^D'
```